# Component does not re-render after changes done by event listener in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

I have the following Angular component with a listener that will update imageData given an event:

```
@Component({
    selector: "home",
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent{
    mediafilepicker: Mediafilepicker;
    imageData: string;
    imageDataPrefixed: string;

    constructor(){
        this.mediafilepicker = new Mediafilepicker();
        this.mediafilepicker.on("getFiles", (res) => {
            let results = res.object.get('results');
            const imageFromLocalFile: ImageSource = <ImageSource> fromFile(results[0].file);
            const b64 = imageFromLocalFile.toBase64String("png");
            console.log(b64);
            this.imageData = b64;
            this.imageDataPrefixed = "data:image/png;base64," + b64;
        });
    }
```

here is my template:

```
<ActionBar title="My App"></ActionBar>

<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
    <Button text="Select an Image" (tap)="onSelectTap()"></Button>
    <Image [src]="imageDataPrefixed"></Image>

</FlexboxLayout>
```

I have an Image component bounded to imageData, and initially, since imageData isn't initialized, it loads nothing in the component.  However after this listener, the member (property?) values update correctly, but the component does not re-render.  It does correctly re-render the Image when something else forces it to re-render.

Should I be putting this listener somewhere else?  Is there a work around?

Thanks.

Comment: HomeComponent should have a decorator.   Don't do this in angular: var self = this;  Use an arrow function: function (res) {  should be (res) => {.  What about the template?

Comment: I did have a decorator, silly of me not to include it in the question, edited

Comment: please show us home.component.html

Comment: sorry, just added as you commented.  Also fixed my code to use an arrow function, will reflect that as well in the question

Comment: Is Image a component? Can you try <Image> ->  <img>

Comment: Try wrapping the callback code inside `ngZone.run(() => { ... })`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199013/1009922).

Comment: @ConnorsFan that worked perfectly! thanks!